# Page returns blank when running the following PHP code(503)

Tags: php, session

I am running a code that's supposed to pull a questionnaire from a database for evaluation by a user with a valid session.

However, the page returns a blank incomplete page while running this php code.

Am I missing something here?

---

```
<?php
    session_start();

    try
    {
        if(!isset($_SESSION['logged-in']))
        {
            header("Location: ../index.php");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $e)

    {

    }


    // php classes
    require_once("../classes/database.php");
    require_once("../classes/questionnaire.php");
    require_once("../classes/competency.php");
    require_once("../classes/candidate.php");
    require_once("../classes/participant.php");
    require_once("../classes/progress.php");
    require_once("../classes/user.php");
    require_once("../classes/page.php");


    // candidate details
    if($_SESSION['usertype'] == 'candidate') // if user is doing a self evaluation
    {
        $candidatename = User::getName($_SESSION['id']);
        $candidateusername = $_SESSION['username'];

        // questionnaire object
        $q = new Questionnaire(Questionnaire::getQuestionnaireName($_SESSION['id']));

    }

    else if($_SESSION['usertype'] == 'participant') // if user is evaluating their candidate
    {
        $candidatename = User::getName(Participant::getCandidateID(NULL, $_SESSION['id']));
        $candidateusername = Participant::getCandidate($_SESSION['id']);

        // questionnaire object
        $q = new Questionnaire(Questionnaire::getQuestionnaireName(Participant::getCandidateID(NULL, $_SESSION['id'])));

    }


    $candidateID = User::getUID($candidateusername);

    // objects
    $page = new Page('evaluation');

    $user = new User($_SESSION['username']);

    // page height

    $pagename = $page->name;
    $page->setHeight(0, true, $q->numCompetencies());


?>
```

---

This is the HTML has to be output

```
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/screen.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/ie.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/custom.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/evaluation.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/progress-bar.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/error.css" />

    <!-- JAVASCRIPT -->
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../js/slide/help.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../js/slide/evaluation.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../js/slide/questionnaire.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../js/validation/validateevaluation.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../js/instructions.js"></script>

</head>

<body onload="viewCompetency('#st1')">
    <!-- WEBSITE -->
    <!-- BANNER -->
    <div class="banner">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- logo div -->
            <div class="span-5 logo"></div>
            <!-- menu div -->
            <!-- main menu -->


        </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="topseparator"></div>



    <!-- PAGE CONTENT -->
    <div class="container indexdesktop">

        <?php include("../common/minidashboard.php"); ?>   

        <!-- desktop content -->
        <div class="span-24" style="height: <?php print $page->height.'px'; ?>">

            <!-- CONTENT MODULEBOX -->
            <div class="modulebox-classy">

                <div class="pageheading"><h3><span class="blue">REDMA 360 </span><span class="grey">EVALUATION</span></h3></div>

                <div class="contentwide">
                    <div class="iconswide" id="addcand"></div>


                    <p>Kindly give very candid feedback to the person whose name appears below (candidate)</p>


                    <!-- INSTRUCTIONS -->
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                    <div class="instructions" id="instructionswidth-evaluation">
                        <div class="instructions-heading" onclick="showInstructions()"><div class="instructions-icon"></div>INSTRUCTIONS</div>
                        <div class="instructions-content" id="instructions-content">
                        <p>Click the <span class="italic">Accordian Menu</span> to show the competency you want to evaluate. Give a rating on the drop-down select box according to the <span class="italic">Scoring Key</span> below. When you have completed scoring <span class="italic">ALL</span> competencies in the <span class="italic">Questionnaire</span>, a <span class="strong italic">Done</span> button will show. Click <span class="strong italic">Done</span> to complete your evaluation.</p>
                        <p><h5 class="strong white">SCORING KEY:</h5><ol><li>Demonstrates <span class="strong italic">almost none</span> of the behaviour</li><li>Demonstrates <span class="strong italic">some</span> of the behaviour</li><li>Demonstrates <span class="strong italic">about half</span> of the behaviour</li><li>Demonstrates <span class="strong italic">majority</span> of the behaviour</li><li>Demonstrates the behaviour <span class="strong italic">fully</span></li></ol></p> </div>
                    </div>
                </div>




                <div class="contentwide" id="evaluationwidth">

                <!-- Display Questionnaire -->
                <h3>Welcome to Redma360 Evaluation</h3>
                <h4 class="grey"><span class="blue">QUESTIONNAIRE:</span> <?php print Questionnaire::getQuestionnaireName($user->username);?><br />                            
                <?php 

                    print '<span class="blue">CANDIDATE:</span> '.strtoupper($candidatename);

                    if($user->usertype == 'participant') // if user is evaluating their candidate
                    {
                        print '<br /><span class="blue">PARTICIPANT ('.Participant::getPartType($user->username).'):</span>  '.strtoupper($user->name);
                    }
                ?>  
                </h4>

                <!-- Evaluation Accordian -->    
                <div class="evaluation-container">
                    <form action="evaluationaction.php" name="saveForm" id="saveForm" method="post" >
                        <?php $competenciesEvaluatedArr = Questionnaire::displayEvaluationCompetencies($q->getName(), User::getUID($candidateusername), $user->id); ?>
                        <input type="hidden" name="saveButton" id="saveButton" />
                    </form>
                </div> 
                <?php
                    if($user->competenciesdone == $q->numCompetencies())
                    {
                ?>
                <div class="evaluationthankyou" id="evaluationthankyou">Thank you!</div>
                <div class="evaluationsubmitbutton" id="evaluationsubmitbutton">
                    <form action="evaluationdone.php" name="doneForm" method="post" >
                        <input type="image" name="doneButton" src="../images/button-done-large.png" />
                    </form>
                </div>
                <?php
                    }
                ?>
            </div>       


            <!-- progress bar -->
        <div class="sidebar-progress" id="sideprogress-evaluation">
            <div class="content" id="progress">

                <!-- sidebar heading -->
                <div class="sidebar-subheading-color-blue" id="evaluation-sidebar-heading">See the progress and number of competencies answered so far below. </div>

                <!-- progress bar -->
                <div class="content">
                    <?php Progress::getProgressBar(User::getNumGraded(User::getUID($_SESSION['username'])), Questionnaire::getNumCompetencies($q->getID())); ?>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                </div>

                <div class="modulebox-display">

                    <h4>Competencies Answered So Far</h4>

                    <table class="competenciesevaluated">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Competency</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <?php
                                foreach($competenciesEvaluatedArr as $arr)
                                {
                                    print   '<tr>
                                                <td>'.$arr.'</td>
                                            </tr>';
                                }
                            ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        </div>



        </div>



    </div>

    <!-- FOOTER -->
    <?php include("../common/footer.php"); ?>
</body>
```

Comment: header("Location: ../index.php") try to replace with: header("Location: index.php") or even better provide full address with http insted of index.php

Answer (score 0):

Add exit(0), after the header(....), it may solve your problem.

```
   try
    {
        if(!isset($_SESSION['logged-in']))
        {
            header("Location: ../index.php");
            exit(0);//Add this line
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $e)

    {

    }
```

Comment: @Felix can you accept the solution, if you solved your issue. If someone have same problem they can easily solved.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I was missing a class in the included questionnaire.php file.
Putting error reporting to to my PHP file was very helpful.

Thanks